# Do I have to provide a body response Flask with http 405 error

Tags: python, rest, http, flask

I'm trying to make a flask api with python but I've run into a issue, If i only return a http error code `405` for example the code with fail will the following:

```
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a int.
```

I've attached some code to help illustrate the issue. Removing unnecessary stuff.

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_api import status
@app.route('/weights', methods=['GET','POST'])
def weights():
    if request.method == "GET":
   
        return data,status.HTTP_200_OK

    if request.method == "POST":
        #add to db
        return loc,status.HTTP_201_CREATED
    
return status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED
```

The issue occurs on the last line,which does indeed return an int 405.

If i use `return "junk",status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED` it will work as expected return the 405 and junk.

**Is there any reason why I cant just return the response code? Should I always be returning some html message saying method not allowed or whatever my code is.**

EDIT: Bolded my question which is not answered in those questions, they just state that you have to send an empty string, I'm asking should that always be the case and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An empty string should accomplish what you're after without necessitating a fully-formed error message.

Comment: But should I be adding an full error message response? What would be the standard.